# How do you stop a form from submitting in C# ASP.NET in a conditional if else statement without using Javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an assignment where I need to create a hi/lo game using ASP.NET and I'm having issues with validating data entered into my page by the user. My form will submit even if the regex condition is not met.

I know I could validate this information with javascript easily but I am not allowed to use any javascript in the entire project. Here's my code so far in terms of validation:

```
        {
            string tempName;
            tempName = nameBox.Text;

            if (Regex.IsMatch(tempName, @"^[A-z]+$"))
            {
                ViewState["name"] = tempName;
                Context.Items.Add("name", ViewState["name"].ToString());
                args.IsValid= true;
            }
            else
            {
                nameBox.Text = "";
                args.IsValid= false;
            }
        }
```

```
protected void nameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                //submit
            }
            else
            {
                //do not submit
            }
        }
```

Is there any way for me to stop submission without using javascript and if there is how would I do it?

Comment: You can not stop form submission with C# in asp.net. C# executes on the server. By then the form has been submitted.  You need something client side, traditionally, javascript. Alternatively look at the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

Comment: If you want to run C# on the client side in a web app, you can't do that with ASP.NET Web Forms. You'd have to use [ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), a far newer platform. Which would be a good idea - ASP.NET Web Forms is basically a dead platform that shouldn't be used for new development, it's just that a lot of companies have legacy apps written in it that are time consuming to migrate to a newer platform. And then you have a few oddballs here and there that like it, but they're in the minority.

Comment: Also look at webforms [reg ex validator](https://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/regular-expression-validator/). @mason is right about webforms though. If it's not dead, it's well and truly dying (and I don't actually hate web forms), any new development should avoid it.